Evaluating $ \int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \cos \left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \cos^{\frac{3}{2}}(x) \cos (2 n x) \, dx $ where $n$ is an integer
Could someone suggest a general approach ( e.g. a recursive approach ) for evaluating this in terms of $n$, where $n$ is an integer greater than $0$ ?.
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)
\cos^{3/2}\left(x\right)\cos\left(2nx\right)
{\rm d}x
$$
Using $\tt CAS$ I could found these for discrete values of $n$ - however even from these I could not construct a sequence function in terms of $n$.
$n = 1 : \frac{11 \pi }{64 \sqrt{2}}$
$n = 2 : -\frac{\pi }{128 \sqrt{2}}$
$n = 3 : \frac{3 \pi }{1024 \sqrt{2}}$
$n = 4 : -\frac{3 \pi }{2048 \sqrt{2}}$
$n = 5 : \frac{7 \pi }{8192 \sqrt{2}}$
$n = 6 : -\frac{9 \pi }{16384 \sqrt{2}}$
$n = 7 : \frac{99 \pi }{262144 \sqrt{2}}$
$n = 8 : -\frac{143 \pi }{524288 \sqrt{2}}$
$n = 9 : \frac{429 \pi }{2097152 \sqrt{2}}$
$n = 10 : -\frac{663 \pi }{4194304 \sqrt{2}}$

After my oeis searching, these numerator matches A161200 https://oeis.org/A161200 which suggest to look at series expansion of $(1+x)^{3/2}$... it seems that $n$ case is $1/8\sqrt 2$ times $x^{n+1}$'s coefficient of that series.

@JetfiRex, thanks for this. the numerators do seem to match with the reference you gave. when you say "it seems that n case is...", am I correct that you are referring to the numerators only? since I do not see the pattern for the denominators

Oh you can take the series expansion of $(1+x)^{3/2}$, it is a constant times that. I believe it has something to do with Fourier transform, but I don't know.

Okay, I have managed to give an answer by Fourier transform (as I mentioned yesterday) in the post.

This integral can be reduced to computing a sum of beta integrals. Noting that $\cos 2n x=T_{2n}(\cos x)$, where $T_n$ are the Chebyshev polynomials. Then performing a change of variables $u=\cos x$, the integral is given by
$$I_n=\int_{0}^{1}u^{3/2}\sqrt{\frac{1+u}{2}}T_{2n}(u)\frac{du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{0}^{1}u^{3/2}T_{2n}(u)\frac{du}{\sqrt{1-u}}$$
Even order Chebyshev polynomials can be written in terms of monomials using the formula
$$T_{2n}(x)=n\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}2^{2k}\frac{(n+k-1)!}{(n-k)!(2k)!}x^{2k}~~,~~~~ n>0$$
The integrals to be done after expanding the polynomials are expressible in terms of binomial coefficients
$$\int_0^1u^{2k+3/2}(1-u)^{-1/2}du=\frac{\Gamma(2k+5/2)\Gamma(1/2)}{\Gamma(2k+3)}=\frac{\pi}{2^{4k+3}}{4k+3\choose 2k+1}$$
Putting everything together, we can show that the integrals with $n>0$ can be written as a finite sum
$$I_n=\frac{\pi n}{8\sqrt{2}}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^{n-k}}{2^{2k}(n+k)}{n+k\choose 2k}{4k+3\choose 2k+1}$$

Wonderful! Thanks a lot

Result: For $n>1$,
$$I_n = \int_0^{\pi/2}\cos\frac x2
\cos^{3/2}x\cos(2nx)dx
= \frac{\pi}{8\sqrt2} \binom {3/2}{n+1}
$$
Proof: Substitute $t =\cos x$ along with $\cos (2n x )= T_{2n}(t)$, the Chebyshev polynomials, to evaluate the summation
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty I_n a^{2n}
=& \ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^{3/2}}{\sqrt{1-t}}\bigg( \sum_{n=0}^\infty T_{2n}(t)a^{2n}\bigg)dt\\
 =& \ \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^{3/2}}{\sqrt{1-t}} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \bigg(T_{n}(t)a^n+ T_{n}(-t) a^{n}\bigg)dt\\
 =& \ \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{t^{3/2}}{\sqrt{1-t}}\left(\frac{1-at}{1-2at+a^2}+ \frac{1+at}{1+2at+a^2}\right)dt\\
=& \ \frac{\pi}{8\sqrt2}\bigg[\frac32 + a^2+\frac{(1+a^2)^{3/2}-1}{a^2}\bigg]\\
= &\ \frac{\pi}{8\sqrt2}\bigg[3+\frac{11}8 a^2
+ \sum_{n=2}^\infty \binom {3/2}{n+1}a^{2n}\bigg]
\end{align}
Match the coefficients of $a^{2n}$ to obtain
$I_0=\frac{3\pi}{8\sqrt2}$, $I_1=\frac{11\pi}{64\sqrt2}$
$$I_{n>1}= \frac{\pi}{8\sqrt2} \binom {3/2}{n+1}
 = \frac{3\pi}{8\sqrt2}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(2n-3)!!}{[2(n+1)]!!}
$$

The problem simplify is you use
$$\cos(2nx)=n\,2^{2n}\,\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\, \frac{(2 n-k-1)!}{k! \,(2 (n- k))!}\,2^{-2 k} \,\cos ^{2(n- k)}(x)$$
$$I_n=\int_0^{\frac \pi 2}\cos \left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \cos ^{2 n-2
   k+\frac{3}{2}}(x)\,dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}\,\frac{\Gamma \left(2 n-2
   k+\frac{5}{2}\right)}{\Gamma (2 n-2 k+3)}$$
Using the above
$$J_n=\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \cos \left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \cos
   ^{\frac{3}{2}}(x) \cos (2 n x) \, dx$$
$$J_n=\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}\, 2^{2 n}\, n\,\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\,\frac{2^{-2 k}\, \Gamma \left(2n-2 k+\frac{5}{2}\right)\, \Gamma (2 n-k)}{\Gamma
   (k+1)\, \Gamma (2 n-2 k+1)\, \Gamma (2 n-2 k+3)}$$
Edit (just for your curiosity and given by Mathematica)
$$J_n=-\frac{\pi}{4}   \left(G_{3,3}^{2,1}\left(\frac{1}{2}|
\begin{array}{c}
 -1,\frac{1}{2}-2 n,2 n+\frac{1}{2} \\
 -\frac{5}{2},\frac{1}{2},0 \\
\end{array}
\right)+\sqrt{2} \, _2F_1\left(-2 n,2 n;2;\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)$$ where appear the Meijer G-function and the Gaussian hypergeometric fucntion.

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iverson}[1]{\left[\left[\,{#1}\,\right]\right]}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos\pars{x \over 2}
\cos^{3/2}\pars{x}\cos\pars{2nx}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = & \
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
\cos^{3/2}\pars{x}\,{\cos\pars{\bracks{2n + 1/2}x} +
\cos\pars{\bracks{2n - 1/2}x} \over 2}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = & \ {{\large\tt I}\pars{2n + 1/2} + {\large\tt I}\pars{2n - 1/2} \over 2}
\\[5mm] & \mbox{where}\ \color{red}{{\large\tt I}\pars{\alpha}} \equiv \color{red}{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos\pars{\alpha x}
\cos^{3/2}\pars{x}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = & \
\Re\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\expo{\ic\alpha x}
\cos^{3/2}\pars{x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = & \
\left.\Re\int_{x\ =\ 0}^{x\ =\ \pi/2}z^{\alpha}
\pars{z + 1/z \over 2}^{3/2}\,{\dd z \over \ic z}
\right\vert_{\,z\ \equiv\exp\pars{\ic x}}
\\[5mm] = & \
\left.2^{-3/2}\ \Im\int_{x\ =\ 0}^{x\ =\ \pi/2}
z^{\alpha - 5/2}\
\pars{1 + z^{2}}^{3/2}\,\,\dd z
\right\vert_{\,z\ \equiv\exp\pars{\ic x}}
\\[5mm] = & \
-2^{-3/2}\,\, \Im\int_{1}^{0}
y^{\alpha - 5/2}\expo{\pars{\alpha - 5/2}\pi\ic/2}\,\,
\bracks{1 + \pars{\ic y}^{2}}^{3/2}\,\,\ic\,\dd y
\\[5mm] = & \
2^{-3/2}\cos\pars{\bracks{\alpha - {5 \over 2}}{\pi \over 2}}\int_{0}^{1}
y^{\alpha - 5/2}\ \pars{1 - y^{2}}^{3/2}\,\,\dd y
\\[5mm] & \sr{y^{2}\ \mapsto\ y}{=}
2^{-5/2}\,\cos\pars{\bracks{\alpha - {5 \over 2}}{\pi \over 2}}\int_{0}^{1}
y^{\alpha/2 - 7/4}\,\,\pars{1 - y}^{3/2}\,\,\dd y
\\[5mm] = & \ 
2^{-5/2}\,\cos\pars{\bracks{\alpha - {5 \over 2}}{\pi \over 2}}{\Gamma\pars{\alpha/2 - 3/4}\Gamma\pars{5/2} \over \Gamma\pars{\alpha/2 + 7/4}}
\\[5mm] = & \ 
\color{red}{{3 \over 2^{9/2}}\root{\pi}\,\cos\pars{\bracks{\alpha - {5 \over 2}}{\pi\over 2}}{\Gamma\pars{\alpha/2 - 3/4} \over \Gamma\pars{\alpha/2 + 7/4}}}
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos\pars{x \over 2}
\cos^{3/2}\pars{x}\cos\pars{2nx}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = & \
\bbx{\color{#44f}{\begin{array}{l}
\ds{{3\root{\pi} \over 2^{11/2}}\left[%
\cos\pars{\bracks{n - 1}\pi}{\Gamma\pars{n - 1/2} \over \Gamma\pars{n + 2}}\right.}
\\[2mm] 
\ds{\left.\rule{1.4cm}{0pt}+ \cos\pars{\bracks{n - {3 \over 2}}\pi}{\Gamma\pars{n - 1} \over \Gamma\pars{n + 3/2}}\right].
\\[3mm] \ds{k \in \mathbb{N}_{>\ 0}}}
\end{array}}} \\ &
\end{align}
Note that $\ds{\lim_{n \to k}\braces{\cos\pars{\bracks{n - {3 \over 2}\pi}}\Gamma\pars{n - 1}} = \color{red}{\large\pi}}$ when $\ds{k = 1}$ and $\ds{\color{red}{\large 0}}$ otherwise for integer $\ds{k}$.

How do you justify the passage from line (7) $=2^{3/2}\Im...$ to line (8) $=-2^{3/2}\Im...$?

As I mentioned this in the comment before, this can be done by Fourier transform.
This answer is a closed form (does not contain sum) or fraction in Gamma function.
Let $f(x)$ be a periodic function with period $\pi$ and when $x\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, $f(x)=\cos(x/2)\cos(x)^{3/2}$
By half-angle formula, we have
\begin{align*}
&\cos(x/2)\cos(x)^{3/2}\\
=&\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\sqrt{\cos(x)^3+\cos(x)^4}\\
=&\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\sqrt 2}(\cos(2x)+1)^{3/2}+\frac{1}{4}(\cos(2x)+1)^2}
\end{align*}
Let $z=e^{2ix}$, so it is
\begin{align*}
&\cos(x/2)\cos(x)^{3/2}\\
=&\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\sqrt 2}(\cos(2x)+1)^{3/2}+\frac{1}{4}(\cos(2x)+1)^2}\\
=&\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{8}(z+\frac 1z+2)^{3/2}+\frac{1}{16}(z+\frac 1z+2)^2}\\
=&\frac{1}{4\sqrt 2}\sqrt{2(z+\frac 1z+2)^{3/2}+(z+\frac 1z+2)^2}
\end{align*}
Notice that if we calculate the square of $(1+z)^{3/2}/z+z(1+\frac 1z)^{3/2}$, we can have the expression if we discard the square root:
\begin{align*}
&((1+z)^{3/2}/z+z(1+\frac 1z)^{3/2})^2\\
=&\frac{(1+z)^3}{z^2}+z^2(1+\frac 1z)^3+2(1+z)^{3/2}(1+\frac 1z)^{3/2}\\
=&(1+z)^3/z^2+(1+z)^3/z+2((1+z)(1+\frac 1z))^{3/2}\\
=&(1+z)^4/z^2+2((1+z)(1+\frac 1z))^{3/2}\\
=&{(z+\frac 1z+2)^2}+2(z+\frac 1z+2)^{3/2}.
\end{align*}
Therefore, we have
\begin{align*}
f(x)=&\frac{1}{4\sqrt 2}((1+z)^{3/2}/z+z(1+\frac 1z)^{3/2})\\
=&\frac{1}{4\sqrt 2}((e^{2ix}+1)^{3/2}/e^{2ix}+(e^{-2ix}+1)^{3/2}e^{2ix})
\end{align*}
By series expension, we have
\begin{align*}
(1+z)^{3/2}/z=\frac 1z+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{3/2}{n+1}z^n=\frac 1z+\frac 32+\frac 38z+\sum_{n=2}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{3\times (2n-3)!}{(n-2)!(n+1)!2^{2n-1}}z^n.
\end{align*}
Therefore, the Fourier Coefficient of $\cos(2n\pi)=(-1)^{n-1}\frac{3\times (2n-3)!}{(n-2)!(n+1)!2^{2n-1}}$ for all $n\ge 2$, and is $\frac{11}{8}$ for $n=1$ (it is from $\frac 38e^{2ix}$ and $1\cdot e^{-2ix}$). Therefore, take the inverse Fourier Transform, the integral is $(-1)^{n-1}\frac{3\times (2n-3)!}{(n-2)!(n+1)!2^{2n+3}}\sqrt 2\pi$ for $n\ge 2$, and is $\frac{11\sqrt 2\pi}{128}$ for $n=1$.

Or by using definition of cosine, $f(x)=\frac{e^{-ix}+e^{-2ix}}{4\sqrt2}(1+e^{2ix})^{3/2}$.

@BobDobbs Thank you for your comment. Yes, this is a quicker way, but on the other hand we need to ''eliminate'' $e^{-ix}$ there since we only need these $2nx$ (even number terms). Because I haven't calculated if we included those odd number terms what the function be (it is a function of $[-\pi, \pi)$ instead, but... The $3/2$ power make it out of scope, and I don't want to deal with purely imaginary numbers.). So that's why I need another way to bypass that to eliminate odd number terms.
